# Windows 2008R2 File Screening Management Command Tab Arguments

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have created a new "File Screen" under Windows 2008R2 File Screening Management (part of Administrative Tools / File Server Resource Manager )

In the properties of this File Screen, I'd like to use the "Command" tab to invoke a script, and pass the offending screened file spec to the script as a command line argument.

Firstly I can't seem to get it to invoke my .CMD script, and secondly I cannot find any documentation on what, if any, variables I can pass to the command line.

Would anyone who has used the Command tab successfully care to share some hints or tips on how to make effective use of this?

(I can use the Email tab fine, so for now my Screen sends an email, but I'm keen to get the command tab figured out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly do it this way:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "batch.cmd"
```

Or Powershell

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "script.ps1"
```

Comment: The first one can be writed as `%comspec% "batch.cmd"` ;-)